# How to display PDF from the template file using angular2

Tags: angular, jspdf

i have a pdf button, when i click on that i need pdf view mode to be open in new tab. Can any one help me to solve this.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urkap2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

HTML:

```
  <button class="pull-right" (click)="generateToPdf()">PDF</button>
  <h2>Property Name</h2>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
  <div>
  <strong>Tenant:</strong> ABC Company
  </div>
  <div>
   <strong>Address:</strong> SRS Building, Banglore
  </div>
  <div>
  <strong>Suite:</strong> 100
  </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div>
  <strong>Cap:</strong> 2%
  </div>
[DEMO][1]
    </div>

    </div>
```

TS:

```
 generateToPdf() {


    var doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.setFontSize(40);


    doc.addHTML(this.items.nativeElement, 0, 0, () => {
      doc.save("Invoice" + ".pdf");
    });
  }
```

Here jspdf is not installing but its working in visual studio, but i am getting error when trying to use that.

Comment: make sure you install jspdf with `npm install --save jspdf` I cant see it in your packages.json file. And then you also need to uncomment the import statement for jspdf in your app.component.

Comment: ya i have tried that, it throws an error, saying file server package error

Answer (score 0):

I have used 2 script tags in index.html

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@1.3.3/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable@2.3.1/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
```

This solved my issue.